# Modifying $i inside a form

Tags: php, jquery

so I have a form. The form consists of 10 lines by default. It goes like this:

```
<form method="post" action="actionhere">
<?php 
   for($i=0; $i<10;$i++) {
?>
     <div class='clone_me'>
     <span>Line <?php echo $i;?></span>

     <input type='checkbox' name='ck_<?php echo $i;?>'/>
     <input type='text' name='tx_<?php echo $i;?>'/>
     </div>
<?php } ?>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

So inside the form, we will have 10 rows of checkbox+textbox.

What I'm trying to make is, I want to place a button to add new row (the checkbox+textbox). Now, problem is, I need the $i value (since it's form the for loop). Is that possible that when we click the add row button, the value of $i that we set inside for loop be incremented by 1 on each click? I know we can clone the div using jquery, but how about the $i value?

Comment: Count the total number of existing rows in Javascript. Add the number 1 to it, then it'll be your new `i`.

Comment: You can not modify server side variable i.e. $i using client side scripting i.e. on button click.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are doing it in wrong way you do not need `$i` value inside name attribute you have to use array for it for example

```
  <form method="post" action="test.php">
     <div class='clone_me'>
        <span>Line 1</span>
           <input type='checkbox' name='ck[]'/><!--this field should menditory-->
           <input type='text' name='tx[]'/>
        <span>Line 2</span>
          <input type='checkbox' name='ck[]'/><!--this field should menditory-->
          <input type='text' name='tx[]'/>
     </div>
     <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>
  </form>
```

Now implement this code in actionhere.php

```
<?php
    $cks = $_POST['ck'];
    $txs = $_POST['tx'];

    foreach($cks as $key => $ck) {
        echo $ck."<br>";
        echo $txs[$key]."<br>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, basically no. Your PHP script is already over when the html has been generated. So you can't rely anymore on PHP. But you don't need to make it explicitly appear in your html.
You should count the rows using jquery :

```
var i = $('form').find('.clone_me').length
```

and then add a new row using javascript again :

```
$('form .clone_me:last').clone().insertAfter('form .clone_me:last');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <input type='hidden' name='counter' id='counter'/>
    <input type='checkbox' name='chk' id='chk'/>
    <?php

    $counter=$_POST['counter'];


    for($i=0;$i<=$counter;$i++)

    {
    $chk=$_POST['chk'.$i];
    // Your Insert Code Here
    }



    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this can be but have some limit

if you have no problem with page reload the you can do it is:-

by this way your page will reload and the value in textbox and checkbox will gone:---:)

every time new page generate and send by server to client browser

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 

$ends = $_POST['ttl_rows'];

}else{

$ends = 10;

}

?>



<form method="post" action="#">
<?php 
   for($i=1 ; $i<$ends;$i++) {
?>
     <div class='clone_me'>
     <span>Line <?php echo $i;?></span>

     <input type='checkbox' name='ck_<?php echo $i;?>'/>
     <input type='text' name='tx_<?php echo $i;?>'/>
     </div>
<?php } ?>

<input type='hidden' name='ttl_rows' value='<?php echo ($i+1); ?>'/>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```