# JQuery - count total of div after clone()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my continuation of my previous question: [Modifying $i inside a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805215/modifying-i-inside-a-form)

So now I created the code like this:

```
<form method="post" action="actionhere">
    <div id='clone_me'>
        <?php 
        for($i=1; $i<=1;$i++) {
            ?>

            <span id="title">Line <?php echo $i;?></span>

            <input type='checkbox' name='ck[]'/>
            <input type='text' name='tx[]'/>

        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>
    <input type="button" value="Add row" class="addrow" />
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.addrow').click(function(){                
        var n= $("#clone_me").length;
        var new_n=n+1;              
        var new_line= $('#clone_me div:first').clone().append();                
        $("span#title", new_line).text("Line bet "+new_n+" ");
        new_line.appendTo('#clone_me');
        alert(new_n);               
    });
});
</script>
```

So I can add new row when I click the button, but I want to change the title inside span element, but I can't make it work. The 1st cloned, yes, the title is changed correctly (from 1 to 2), but the 2nd cloned still display "2", not "3".

What is the correct way?

EDIT
I only put $i=1 for testing purposes. In actual application I need to change it to 10 (so will loop 10 rows)

Comment: `clone_me` is a class, not an id...

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: my bad, clone_me is an id, I typed it wrongly.

Comment: `$('#clone_me>div').length;` after the appends will give you the count of all divs within clone.

Comment: @JFit thanks! I modified the html code (before span) inside the loop a bit and use your code, it works!